# How can I work with mongodb regex with special characters like "+" (plus)?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to search values having special characters such as " + " in a document.

```
variable = 'test+test.test';
```

I want to search values with `.*variable.*`,

For example,

```
db.myCollection.find({ myKey : { '$regex' : '.*variable.*','$options' : 'i' });
```

Above queries dont work

Comment: Can you show the documents of your MongoDB collection?

Answer (score 5):

I have solved issue and this is working code.

```js
string = "abcd+1234@gmail.com";

Meteor js query example: {'emails.address': {'$regex': '.*' + Helpers.escapeRegExp(string) + '.*', '$options': 'i'}},


escapeRegExp: function (string) {
    if (string) {
       return string.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
       
    }
}
It should be abcd\+1234@gmail\.com after call escapeRegExp function.
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to search values with `.*variable.*`

You don't need to search with the star operator `.*variable.*`.

The following will work just as fine:

```
// returns all keys with "variable" somewhere in the string
db.myCollection.find({ myKey : /variable/i});
```

> I want to search values having special characters such as " + " in a document.

If you want to do this with a regex, simply escape the `+` character with `\`:

```
db.myCollection.find({ myKey : /test\+test/i});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but my problem in meteor js so my query in meteor is  -  Meteor.users.find(query,{limit:limit,skip:skip,sort:sortby}) and in meteor server side myCollection.find({ myKey : /test\+test/i}); not working, my regex query is  query = {'emails.address': {'$regex': '.*' + customQuery.searchText + '.*', '$options': 'i'}}

Answer (score 0):

```
variable = 'test\+test\.test';
```

then

```
db.myCollection.find({ myKey : { '$regex' : '.*'+variable+'.*','$options' : 'i' });
```